# Rsync Failed to exec ssh

Tags: windows, git, ssh, rsync

Приветствую!
Пытался файл большого размера скинуть на git через git-annex и наткнулся на проблему с git for windows:

> **protocol version mismatch -- is your shell clean?** (see the rsync man
>   page for an explanation) rsync error: protocol incompatibility (code
>   2) at /home/lapo/package/rsync-3.0.9
>   -1/src/rsync-3.0.9/compat.c(174) [Receiver=3.0.9]

Вот вывод с ключом "-vvvv":

> cmd= machine=gitlab.local user=root path= cmd[0]=ssh cmd[1]=-l
>   cmd[2]=root cmd[3]=gitlab.local cmd[4]=rsync cmd[5]=--serve r
>   cmd[6]=-vvvve.Lsf cmd[7]=. cmd[8]= opening connection using: ssh -l
>   root gitlab.local rsync --server -vvvve.Lsf .
>
> note: iconv_open("UTF-8", "UTF-8") succeeded. rsync: Failed to exec
>   **ssh: No such file or directory (2)** rsync error: error in IPC code
>   (code 14) at /home/lapo/package/rsync-3.0.9-1/src
>   /rsync-3.0.9/pipe.c(84) [sender=3.0.9] (Client) Protocol versions:
>   remote=1852142427, negotiated=30 protocol version mismatch -- is your
>   shell clean? (see the rsync man page for an explanation) [sender]
>   _exit_cleanup(code=2, file=/home/lapo/package/rsync-3.0.9-1/src/rsync-3 .0.9/compat.c,
>   line=174): entered rsync error: error in IPC code (code 14) at
>   /home/lapo/package/rsync-3.0.9-1/src /rsync-3.0.9/compat.c(174)
>   [sender=3.0.9] [sender] _exit_cleanup(code=2,
>   file=/home/lapo/package/rsync-3.0.9-1/src/rsync-3 .0.9/compat.c,
>   line=174): about to call exit(14)

Я так понимаю rsync не видит ssh? В то же время "where" не видит rsync но видит ssh а git-annex видит rsync (они оба в директории c:\git\cmd).

- Git-2.5.0-64-bit
- git-annex distributionVersion = "5.20150812"
- Windows 7 Pro SP1 Version 6.1.7601

Результат выполнения `echo %PATH%`:

> C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\A MD\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\Zero Install;C:\Git\cmd;C:\Git\mingw64\b in;C:\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\GPAC;C:\Program Files\GPAC

Кстати, при попытке воспользоваться "ssh host -l login" выходит следующее:

> Достигнут уровень рекурсии, максимально возможный для команды `SETLOCAL`. Unable to enable delayed expansion. Immediate expansion will be used. Слишком длинная входная строка. Ошибка в синтаксисе команды. `c:\Git\cmd>@set PATH=c:\Git\bin;c:\Git\mingw\bin;install_root%\mingw\bin;%PATH%`

Прошу помощи.

Comment: Кстате при попытке воспользоваться "ssh host -l login" выходит следующее: Достигнут уровень рекурсии, максимально возможный для команды SETLOCAL.
Unable to enable delayed expansion. Immediate expansion will be used.
Слишком длинная входная строка.
Ошибка в синтаксисе команды.

c:\Git\cmd>@set PATH=c:\Git\bin;c:\Git\mingw\bin;install_root%\mingw\bin;%PATH%

Comment: Для Git есть специализированный инструмент [git-sync](https://github.com/ianb/git-sync), можно попробовать его вместо rsync.

Comment: @NickVolynkin судя по исходному коду он тоже использует rsync.